# Hold column group together in crosstab

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I created a report in iReport with a crosstab containing 2 ColumnGroups.
If the crosstab contains more columns than fitting on the page, they are (correctly) continued on the next page. But how can I prevent JR from splitting inside a column group (so if the next column group doesn´t fit on the page, start it on the next page).

Example of colGroups i my crosstab:

Category 1          Category 2      **Category 3**

C1   C2   C3     C1   C2   C3    **C1**

**Category 3


C2  C3**

Answer (score 0):

hope this will useful; inside jasper report on crosstab option there's a checkbox called "keeptogether"; this chekbox keep table on the same page without splitting it

Comment: I cannot find an option called "keeptogether" for crosstabs, at least not in iReport. And also not in Jasper online ref ...